# SQL select query to merge rows

Tags: sql, mysql, group-concat

I have a single MySQL database:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Email                 | Name                      | Tag
-------------------------------------------------------------------
test@test.com         |Test Person               | TagOne
test@test.com         |Test Person               | Tag Two
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Need an SQL query that will return

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Email                 | Name                      | Tag
-------------------------------------------------------------------
test@test.com         |Test Person               | TagOne, Tag Two
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.email,
         t.name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.tag ORDER BY t.tag SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.email, t.name
```

Reference:

- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Wow! Only just saw your post as got confused thinking it was mine. We posted at the same time! What a great forum. Will be back. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to do this and is stuck:

```
SELECT Email, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Tag ORDER BY Tag ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM Table
GROUP BY Email
```

Comment: Beware of MySQL's hidden column in the GROUP BY & HAVING clauses - it's non-standard, and will not port to other databases: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html