# Merge two rows that contain the same Id but different data into one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a very tricky question for you all

Suppose I have the following tables

Table **AccountType**:

```
Id       Type
 1     Checking
 2      Savings
```

Table **Customer_Account**:

```
Customer_Id      Account_Type_Id
    450                 1
    450                 2
    451                 1
```

The table **Customer_Account** contains a list of Customers' Ids with their Account type Ids. The Account_Type_Id is a foreign key coming from the AccountType.Id.

Suppose in the **Customer_Account** table, a customer named Josh (id 450) can have **both** a checking and a savings account as shown above. I can output this customer with his id and type of account like so by having a LEFT JOIN twice on the **AccountType** table:

```
SELECT CustAccount.Customer_Id AS Id, Account1.Type AS Account_Type_1, Account2.Type AS Account_Type_2
FROM Customer_Account CustAccount
LEFT JOIN AccountType Account1
ON Account1.Id = CustAccount.Account_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN AccountType Account2
ON Account2.Id = CustAccount.Account_Type_Id
```

The output will be:

```
 Id        Account_Type_1         Account_Type_2           
450           Checking               Checking 
450           Savings                Savings
451           Checking               Checking
```

What I'm trying to do is that if a customer like Josh (id 450) has **both** a checking and a savings account, I want to output the two rows of data above into one row like so:

```
 Id        Account_Type_1      Account_Type_2
450           Checking            Savings
```

And also, if a customer has only one type of account (like customer with id 451 here), I want only that type of account to appear under the corresponding column like so:

```
 Id        Account_Type_1      Account_Type_2
451           Checking
```

Or if customer with id 451 had only a Savings account the ouput should be:

```
Id        Account_Type_1      Account_Type_2
451                              Savings
```

I want 'Checking' to only appear under Accoun_Type_1 and 'Savings' under Account_Type_2. If I do a GROUP BY CustAccount.Customer_Id, I get this:

```
 Id        Account_Type_1      Account_Type_2
450           Checking            Checking
451           Checking            Checking
```

Any help from any expert will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what your tables look like. The table 'Customers' has a field 'Account_Id' and a field 'Customer_Id'? And 'Josh' appears twice in this table, both with the same Customer_Id?

Comment: The table Customers has columns Id, Name, Account_Type_1, Account_Type_2 and Account_Type_Id (Foreign Key from table AccountType)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're confused here. Account_Type_1 is a name you're introducing in the result set of your query, it doesn't seem to be a column in your Customers table.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually Account_Id, not Account_Type_Id

Comment: And what about Account_Type_1 ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the table Customers contains only the columns, Id, Name and Account_Id (foreign key from AccountType table). The fields Account_Type_1 and Account_Type_2 are what I want to display in the ouput of my SQL query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3140/discussion-between-arnout-engelen-and-user765368)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a straight-forward application for a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ac1.id, ac2.id) AS id, ac1.Account_Type_1, ac2.Account_Type_2
  FROM (SELECT c.Customer_ID AS Id, t.Type AS Account_Type_1
          FROM Customer_Account AS c
          JOIN AccountType      AS t ON c.Account_Type_ID = t.ID AND t.ID = 1) AS ac1
  FULL OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT c.Customer_ID AS Id, t.Type AS Account_Type_2
          FROM Customer_Account AS c
          JOIN AccountType      AS t ON c.Account_Type_ID = t.ID AND t.ID = 2) AS ac2
    ON ac1.Id = ac2.Id;
```

If your DBMS does not support FULL OUTER JOIN but does support LEFT OUTER JOIN, then you can use:

```
SELECT ac0.id, ac1.Account_Type_1, ac2.Account_Type_2
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.Customer_ID AS Id FROM Customer_Account AS c) AS ac0
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT c.Customer_ID AS Id, t.Type AS Account_Type_1
          FROM Customer_Account AS c
          JOIN AccountType      AS t ON c.Account_Type_ID = t.ID AND t.ID = 1) AS ac1
    ON ac0.id = ac1.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT c.Customer_ID AS Id, t.Type AS Account_Type_2
          FROM Customer_Account AS c
          JOIN AccountType      AS t ON c.Account_Type_ID = t.ID AND t.ID = 2) AS ac2
    ON ac0.Id = ac2.Id;
```

The first sub-query generates the list of customer IDs that exist; the second generates the list for account type 1 (Checking); the third generates the list for account type 2 (Saving).  The joins ensure that every account is properly recognized.

Answer (score 1):

i think [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010206109.aspx) should help you

[1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010206109.aspx): [Sql Select Query Question. Merge Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845444/sql-select-query-question-merge-rows) or else

[this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010206109.aspx) should help you

Comment: As for the first link, it's not the same problem as mine. In their problem they had only one column in their table with different values. Me, I have two columns with alternating different values, it's different. What I want is really a GROUP BY kind of thing to merge those two rows into a single row in a table. As for the Union, I believe it only works between two SELECT statement. Can I not really do this with just one SELECT statement?

Answer (score 1):

Adding more conditions to your ON clauses:

```
ON Account1.Id = CustAccount.Account_Type_Id and Account1.Account_Type_Id = 1

ON Account2.Id = CustAccount.Account_Type_Id and Account2.Account_Type_Id = 2
```

will result in output that includes the account(s) held by the customer.  If they only have one account then the other account type will be NULL.

Edit: Sorry, I failed to appreciate that you don't have a table of customers.  You can create a temporary table with a list of distinct Customer_Id values and use that as the first table in your JOINs.

```
select distinct Customer_Id into #Customers
    from Customer_Account
```

Or the much more straightforward:

```
select distinct C.Customer_Id,
    ( select 'Checking' from Customer_Account where Customer_Id = C.CustomerId and Account_type_Id = 1 ) as Account_Type_1,
    ( select 'Savings' from Customer_Account where Customer_Id = C.CustomerId and Account_type_Id = 2 ) as Account_Type_2,
    from Customer_Account as C
```

Comment: There's no column Account_Type_Id in the AccountType table but I see what you mean. It does not work because it still shows up twice and also now it outputs NULL for the second account Type

Comment: Select 'Checking' from Customer_Account?

Comment: You could use a lookup to get the account type ("Checking") from the id (1), or just SELECT a constant.  The result of the correlated subquery will be either the constant value or NULL.  COALESCE or CASE can be used to supply a default value, e.g. "n/a".  Try playing with: SELECT 42 AS ANSWER, ( SELECT 'ME' WHERE 1 = 2 ) AS CHOSEN